# UI bug onClick event with React 18 and SocketIO using middleware and Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, socket.io

I have a website which is experiencing a UI bug which someone may be able to help point out my err.
I suspect it has to do with batching, but I could be wrong.

When a user updates a record, that record is updated in an ExpressJS backend along with two slightly intensive calculation within the backend are run on about 30,000 records and then emits a websocket event with the updated record, updatedMetrics1, updatedMetrics2.

Below is how my backend handles this.

```
    //Do the things here....  
    // Things completed, now emit socket event and respond to client...
      io.emit('indv', {individual: singleIndividual, ijMetrics: newJobMetrics, ieMetrics: newEmployerMetrics, isNew: false});

      const formattedIndividual = returnIndividualType(results.rows);
      res.status(200).send({message: 'Individual Updated!', data: {individuals: formattedIndividual} });
```

So, event 'indv' is sent out to all subscribed users and updates that individual record, along with adding updatedMetrics1 and updatedMetrics2 within their respective redux stores.

`res.status(200).send(...)` is for the user that updated the record, **this response is what triggers image #2**

1. Is the updating modal.
   [image]
2. Is the successfully saved data this modal is triggered by `res.status(200).send(...)`.
   [image]
3. Is the page when users click the button in image #2.
   [image]

Now...this is the interesting part.
**When image #2 appears, I click it...and it 'freezes'. Once the middleware handles the three dispatch functions  the navigation finishes and you get image #3**

I suspect the middleware is blocking the state change and navigation logic. Most likely due to bad architecture of the code below.

```
      socket.on('indv', (res) => {
        console.info('indv event received, ', res);
        //send individual object
        mwStore.dispatch(socketIndividualPayload(res));
        mwStore.dispatch(socketJobMetrics({ijMetrics: res.ijMetrics, isNew: res.isNew}));
        mwStore.dispatch(socketEmployerMetrics({ieMetrics: res.ieMetrics, isNew: res.isNew}));
      });
```

Why is it doing this? It 'feels' like my click button event is being queued after the middleware dispatches. I put a console log on image #2's button and sure enough, this logged the message AFTER my `mwStore.dispatch(socketEmployerMetrics({ieMetrics: res.ieMetrics, isNew: res.isNew}));` action completed.

In dev environment, it is instant and I don't experience this 'freeze/hang' UI.

Looking at my live site's dev tools, my socket.emit('indv') is returning super fast, which leads me to suspect it's how I've setup my middleware mwStore.dispatch() functions.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

So I broke up the dispatch to three separate events, and it worked in production.

This was my solution, incase anyone comes across a similar race condition and UI rendering problem.

Changed my middleware to this:

```
      socket.on('indv', (res) => {
        console.info('indv event recieved, ', res);
        //send individual object
        mwStore.dispatch(socketIndividualPayload(res));
      });
      socket.on('jMetric', (res) => {
        console.log('Job Metrics Socket recieved');
        mwStore.dispatch(socketJobMetrics({ijMetrics: res.ijMetrics, isNew: res.isNew}));
      });
      socket.on('eMetric', (res) => {
        console.log('Employer Metrics Socket recieved');
        mwStore.dispatch(socketEmployerMetrics({ieMetrics: res.ieMetrics, isNew: res.isNew}));
      });
```

backend socket emits to this

```
        io.emit('indv', {individual: singleIndividual, isNew: false});
        io.emit('jMetric', {ijMetrics: newJobMetrics, isNew: false});
        io.emit('eMetric', {ieMetrics: newEmployerMetrics, isNew: false});
```

verbose, but solved the UI bug.